# To remark that / faire remarquer: "advertir"?

Tags: traducción

What about that word now? "Advertir"

I always wondered how to translate "faire remarquer" from french or "to remark that" (sthg, to sb) from english, in spanish.

Would "Advertir" do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where I come from, "advertir" is more like "to give a warning". I think either "hacer notar" or "destacar" feels more natural.

Ejemplo/Example:
"Quisiera destacar que esto nunca antes había sucedido."

Answer (score 7):

"Notar", "hacer notar" or even "remarcar" are better translations than "advertir".

Comment: How can you use "remarcar" in this context? "Les hago remarcar que ..." ?

Comment: Like any other verb: "Les remarco que..." or "me gustaría remarcar/remarcarles" in a formal context.

Answer (score 3):

The word "advertir" translates most closely to "to warn."  "Notar" or "mencionar" would be my preference.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.StackExchange! Check our [FAQ] to read our rules, and we hope to see your contributions regularly! :)

Comment: Thanks!  I found my way here from the programming page, and I saw the Spanish page and figured I'd check it out and see if I could help in any way.